# MySql Query efficiency when update

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure if yes, but I want to know if there are better or most efficiently query for do it:

```
UPDATE ranking_tweets 
   SET chequeado = 0 
 WHERE id_publicacion IN (SELECT id 
                            FROM publicaciones 
                           WHERE fecha >= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Table ranking_tweets has >90.000 rows and publicaciones also has >90.000 rows. So this query takes long time to process (> 180 segs).

Can you suggest another better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the query plan?

Comment: Use a join, and index the tables appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE ranking_tweets t
  JOIN publicaciones p
    ON p.id = t.id_publicacion
   SET t.chequeado = 0 
 WHERE p.fecha >= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY;
```